# deploy hadoop with juju

Tags: juju

why after to run the command:

```
juju deploy hadoop hadoop-master --to 7
```

obtain this error

```
ERROR cannot upload charm to provider storage: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 500 Internal Server Error (<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 1.1.1.10 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
)
```

thanks

Comment: Can you add where you are getting the error from?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your MAAS is not configured correctly or has stopped running, because since you're able to run `juju deploy` you *do* have a juju environment bootstrapped. Can you access your MAAS web UI from the URL specified in your `$HOME/.juju/environments.yaml` ? Checking the documentation of MAAS - http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/juju-quick-start.html  might also help.